# How to enter a command on /dev/ttyACM3?

Tags: tty

The device manual I am using says:

> To use the internal GPS, use the following commands on `/dev/ttyACM3` port:
>
> ```
> at$gpsp=1
> at$gpsnmun=2,1,1,1,1,1,1
> ```

How to enter a command on `/dev/ttyACM3`?

Answer (score 1):

You need a program like `screen` or `minicom`. To use that, you will need to know the baud rate the serial port is expecting, *e.g.* 115200. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/40959/how-do-i-connect-to-tty-com-dev-ttyusb0

Comment: Thank you, Aaron.  That helps.

Comment: Then traditionally you would upvote the answer and check it as an accepted if it was correct.